# How can I find slope of the following?

Tags: calculus

please check this image http:// i.stack.imgur.com/tWF8u.jpg

[image]

How did they find slope please help

Comment: Re-write x + y + 2 = 0 as y = (.) x + [.]. The slope is (.).

Comment: @jdjjdjfjd Quite unclear problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate for me ,I didnt understand that

Comment: @user41736 Well please check the image I have highlighted a part can I know how can I find the slope of it?

Comment: Please someone help me please

Comment: @jdjjdjfjd Since $x+y+2=0$ then $y=-x-2$ so what is the slope of this line?. Surely differentiate it and get $-1$  You also know that the slope of a line perpendicular to another has a slope which is negative reciprocal of that line so the slope of the perpendicular will be $-(1/-1)=1$ Is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $x+y+2=0$, can be rearranged to $y=-x-2$. The gradient of that equation is -1 as the equation is in the form $y=mx + b$, where m is the gradient of the line. In this case $m=-1$.

If you're confused about the perpendicular part, the perpendicular gradient is found by: $$m_1 m_2 = -1$$
Where $m_1$ is the gradient of the first line (the x+y+2=0, which is y=-x-2) and the $m_2$ is the gradient of the line perpendicular to it (these are interchangeable, but don't worry about that for now). So then the gradient of my first line is $m_1 = -1$

$$\therefore -1m_2=-1$$
$$m_2=1$$

Comment: It sure is a great answer but using the formula slope of ax+by+c = -a/b.Helps me solve it straightforward.

Comment: Ok, as long as you got it in the end :)

Answer (score 1):

Well after some searching ,I was astonished I forgot 
slope of ax+by+c is -a/b
just posting if some one might be cobfused as Im